# Help identifying Lego Set from bags!

Tags: building, piece-information, sets, instructions

I visited Toyrus in Paris recently and bought several lego sets for my son.  Mostly, Star Wars sets.  In each case, we brought the manuals and the cardboard boxes so that he could assemble them.  However, we also bought some sort of car / racing set, but we forgot to bring the box and manuals.  We have no idea what it is so as to find the instructions on the internet.  Are the photos below enough to identify them?  There are no numbers other than a reference to a 2011 set.  It´s 6 small bags, and four other small bags.  Not sure if the last one full of wheels is a separate set we bought just to increase the number of wheels.  Any help will be truly appreciated. Thanks, Pablo

[image: Bag x3]

[image: Bag x2]

[image: Bag x1]

[image: Bag x]

[image: Bag y]

[image: Bag x]

[image: Bag 6]

[image: Bag 5]

[image: Bag 4]

[image: Bag 3]

[image: Bag 2]

[image: Bag 1]

Answer (score 8):

The city people pack is probably [9348: Community Minifigure Set](http://brickset.com/sets/9348-1/Community-Minifigure-Set) based on the clasic space minifig print.

The numbered bags are probably from [4635: Fun With Vehicles](http://brickset.com/sets/4635-1/Fun-With-Vehicles) - that's based on the colours and the lime green/"bright yellow/green" cap.

I think the first 2 bags are from [6118: Wheels and Tyres](http://brickset.com/sets/6118-1/Wheels-and-Tyres). This set has the same number of the small (8x) and bigger (6x) yellow wheels

Comment: Good spot - I was trying to place those Skeleton heads too - they're on the snowmen.

Comment: I think the first 2 bags are from [6118: Wheels and Tyres](http://brickset.com/sets?query=6118). This set has the same number of the small (8x) and bigger (6x) yellow wheels.

Comment: Hi Joost, and welcome to LEGO Answers - you can edit your answer to include the updated info from your comment - I'd also be happy if you added in my answer if you think it's correct - I'll delete mine, and we'll have a single definitive answer then ;)

Answer (score 2):

The numbered bags are probably from [4635: Fun With Vehicles](http://brickset.com/sets/4635-1/Fun-With-Vehicles) - that's based on the colours and the lime green/"bright yellow/green" cap.

However even with [9348 Community Minifigure Set](http://brickset.com/sets/9348-1/Community-Minifigure-Set) there's still an unidentified bag of wheels...

Comment: Thnak you guys, you are the best.

Comment: It was definitely 4635.

Comment: Community figures also correct.  Wheels probably bought an extra set (my wife insisted on them, now I recall).  Hell of a lego team archeologists!!!

Comment: I've combined all this into [Joost's answer](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/3041/56) so that you can accept a "single good answer" ;)